# Python - Class Scope

Tags: python

I have a python class that works great.

However I need to replace a function from another class as part of my class.

```
class myclass:

   def display(self, jobid):   #Self here is referencing my class
       zoom = NavigationToolbar2.zoom
       def new_zoom(self, *args, **kwargs):
           if self.blurEnabled:    #Self is referencing NavigationToolbar2 Instance instead of my class
               self.toggleBlur()   #Self is referencing NavigationToolbar2 Instance instead of my class
           zoom(self, *args, **kwargs)
       NavigationToolbar2.zoom = new_zoom
```

The code here works great, except for I am unable to acces my own class so my own functions fail. Is anyone able to help??

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code. And it seems that you ought to be **inheriting** from the `NavigationToolbar2` class and overriding the `zoom` function instead of monkey patching it.

Comment: Yes sorry, the only issue is all code needs to be indented one more place except the 1st line... iWill try to fix. (Copy paste error)

Comment: Are you sure that you want to replace NavigationToolbar2.zoom function with your own function (so everytime you use NavigationToolbar2.zoom it would use your new_zoom instead), or do you want to create class that behaves like NavigationToolbar2, while its zoom function behaves different? Because your architecture looks strange.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to run the built in zoom function, as well as some additional code, following Krumelurs guidance...the problem is resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the variable `self` gets overloaded in your inner scope. Try renaming it, e.g.

```
class myclass:

   def display(self, jobid):   #Self here is referencing my class
       zoom = NavigationToolbar2.zoom
       def new_zoom(toolbar, *args, **kwargs):
          ...
       NavigationToolbar2.zoom = new_zoom
```

Comment: Thank you very much, in many years I have never thought to do this (rename self) and I definately wouldnt have tried that! Seems to work great.

Comment: Yes, I agree it goes against intuition. But in this particular case (patching instance methods), it's the least bad way I've found